# C error:format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *'but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[100]'

Tags: c, struct, compiler-warnings, c-strings, strcpy

I'm working on an exercise in c the last few days and I'm having this warning (as the title suggests). I've tried a bunch of stuff but I don't really know how to exactly fix this. I'm not good at programming so there are mistakes. Below are the structs I'm using (which cannot be changed because that's how they are given):

```
    typedef struct bookR* book;
struct bookR{
    char author[MAXSTRING];
    enum genres{fiction,scientific,politics};
    int id;
    char review[MAXLINES][MAXSTRING];

};

typedef struct nodeR* node;
struct nodeR{
    book b;
    node next;

};

typedef struct listR* list;
struct listR{
    node head, tail; 
    int size;
};
```

And here is part of the code where the problem occurs:

```
 void addBook(book b, list bList){
char author [MAXSTRING];
int id;
char review [MAXSTRING][MAXLINES];
printf ("Give the author,`enter code here` id and review of the new book respectively");
scanf("%s",author);
scanf("%d",&id);
scanf("%s",review);
node k=(node)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeR));
assert(k);
k->next=NULL;
strcpy(k->b->author,author);
k->b->id=id;
strcpy(k->b->review,review[MAXSTRING]);}
```

And this is the warning I'm getting:

```
  warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *' but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat=]
scanf("%s",review);
warining:passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer tupe [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
strcpy(k->b->review,review[MAXSTRING]);
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for your time and sorry for the long post.

Comment: `scanf("%s",review)` --> `scanf("%s",review[index])`

Comment: I think the solution is hidden in the warning itself.

Comment: `strcpy(k->b->review,review[MAXSTRING]);` --> `strcpy(k->b->review[index,review[MAXSTRING-1]);`

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @LPs you missed a `]`.

Comment: @Tordek I already edited. ;)

Comment: Don't edit your post with your corrections: it makes hard to understand answers or comments for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Warning No1**

  In order to use `scanf`, you need to pass a *pointer* to it. You have declared :

  ```
  char review [MAXSTRING][MAXLINES];
  ```

  but you read :

  ```
  scanf("%s",review);
  ```

  You need to change this to :

  ```
  scanf("%s", review[i]);
  ```

  where `i` is an index from `0` to `MAXSTRING-1`.
- **Warning No2**

  Moreover, the statement :

  ```
  strcpy(k->b->review,review[MAXSTRING]);
  ```

  gets out of bounds, as you the positions of your array reach `review[MAXSTRING-1]`. Apart from that, you are assigning a *line* to a whole *array*. So you should change it to :

  ```
  strcpy(k->b->review[index], review[MAXSTRING-1]);
  ```

---

**Two more notes :**

1. See this [link on why not to cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
2. Keep in mind that in a declaration such as :

   ```
   array[x][y];
   ```

   `x` indicates the lines and `y` indicates the columns. You have them in the opposite way, so make sure that you do not get confused and that you really access rows when you want rows and columns when you want columns.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I don't understand why it gets out of bounds. I changed it to `strcpy(k->b->review, review[MAXSTRING-1]);`but I get the same error

Comment: Wow, your edited post is so much better. I know about the arrays but I didn't notice that I had switched the Lines with the columns. About the casting of malloc: in class the've said us to cast the result. Do you suggest it is `node k=malloc(sizeof(struct nodeR));`. Can I use malloc like that?

Comment: @Karamanis Yes of course you can! :) This is the correct programming technique but if you are working on a class project, probably you should do what your teacher asks :)

Comment: and if your teacher says you to cast `malloc` return using [tag:c]....change school or class ;)

Answer (score 3):

**1st warning**

```
char review [MAXSTRING][MAXLINES];
```

it is a matrix, that can be seen as an array of C-strings in your case.

Each C-String is `review[index]` where index goes from `0` to `MAXSTRING-1`

So

```
scanf("%s",review)
```

is wrong because of you must pass a single C-String to function, then you must write:

```
scanf("%s",review[index]);
```

I'd suggest you to limit the input string to the maximum allowed chars for each string `MAXLINES-1` using, instead of `scanf`:

```
fgets(review[index], MAXLINES, stdin);
```

**2nd warning**

Same thing for `review` member of `struct bookR`.
So

```
strcpy(k->b->review,review[MAXSTRING]);
```

must be

```
strcpy(k->b->review[index],review[MAXSTRING-1]);
```

As you can see there is a second problem into your strcpy call: the second parameter address your array of strings out of bound, that invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Other warnings**

There is an warning more into your code:

```
test.c:666:45: warning: declaration does not declare anything
     enum genres{fiction,scientific,politics};
                                             ^
```

**Final Considerations**

I guess you want to switch defines into your matrix definitions, as you done into `struct bookR`, like:

```
char review [MAXLINES][MAXSTRING];
```

I Think could be a best choice to ask for each single data with a specific `prinf` ans its `scanf`/`fgets`.

```
printf ("Give the author: ");
fgets(author, MAXSTRING, stdin);
printf ("Enter id: ");
scanf("%d",&id);
printf ("Enter review of the new book respectively: ");
fgets(review[index], MAXSTRING, stdin);
```

Comment: The First warning I get it. But the second one stil has a problem i changed it to `strcpy(k->b->review[index,review[MAXSTRING-1]);`. But I get the same error. Is it because of "As you can see there is a second problem into your strcpy call: the second parameter address your array of strings out of bound, that invoke Undefined Behavior" that you said.`test.c:666:45: warning: declaration does not declare anything
     enum genres{fiction,scientific,politics};` Oops I forgot about that, I know how to fix it.

Comment: @Karamanis How did you declare and init `index`?  See my edit

Comment: @LPs this is because you had the typo in your answer before your edit :)

Comment: @LPs  You're about the typo but I still got the same error. The way you reccomend does seem a lot better. I'll try it and inform you. Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: @Karamanis I don't know about your compiler, my `gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2` compiles without warnings. :)