# C:How to load a list from a file and save it at the end of the program

Tags: c, list, struct, save

I'm working on two functions. The first one loads a list from a file into the program (at the start) and the second one saves the list's data to the file. I've tried to write the two functions but I'm having a hard time(I'm not really good at programming). Here are the structs I'm using I'm also adding the define of index and the creation of the list:

```
#define index 30

typedef struct dataR* data;
    struct dataR{
        int age;
        char name[index];

    };

    typedef struct nodeR* node;
    struct nodeR{
        data a;
        node next;

    };

    typedef struct listR* list;
    struct listR{
        node head, tail, curr; 
        int size;
    };

list list_create(){
    list List=malloc(sizeof(struct listR));
    assert(List);
    List->head=NULL;
    List->tail=NULL;
    List->curr=NULL;
    List->size=0;
    return List;
}
```

Here is the function to load the file data into the list (at the start of the program). Obviously it is wrong but I don't know how to load the data to each node since the list is empty:

```
    list load(char *filename, list List)
    {
       FILE *fd=fopen("filename","r");
       fscanf(fd, "%d",&(List->head->a->age));
       fscanf(fd, "%s",&(List->head->a->name[index-1]));
       fclose(fd);
       fd=NULL;
    }
```

And here is the function that save all of the list's data at the end of the program :

```
    void save(char *filename, list List)
    {
       FILE *fd=fopen("filename.dat","w");
       if (fd==NULL)
       {
          printf("File does not exist");
          return;
       }
       fwrite(List->head->a, sizeof(struct dataR),1,fd);
       node tmp=List->head->next;
       while(tmp->next!=NULL)
       {
          fwrite(tmp->next->a, sizeof(struct dataR),1,fd);
          tmp=tmp->next;
       }

       fclose(fd);
       fd=NULL;
    }
```

The data in the file should look kind like this:

```
35 Nick
29 Jim
19 Helen
```

Well, ofcourse the functions don't do that as they are. So I need some help to improve them. Any tips (on files) and help is much appreciated.I'm sorry for the long post. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to ask a *specific* question ("I need help" is not specific). It seems both your load and save are wrong. So focus on just one of them at a time and ask a specific question about that.

Comment: You never allocate any memory for your list or its elements.

Comment: @kaylum What I should change? That's my question. I think the topic is specific.

Comment: Could you change `char name[index];` to `char name[20];`? where do you define `index`? At the same time, please change `fscanf(fd, "%s",&(List->head->a->name[index]));` to `fscanf(fd, "%s", List->head->a->name);`?

Comment: This question come from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291409/c-errorformat-s-expects-argument-of-type-char-but-argument-2-has-type-ch) Post the relevant part of your code, or the whole code if it is not too long, and sho declaration of all variables used by your code. And a side note: close the previous question choosing one of the answers...

Comment: your load function uses `fscanf`, so your save function should use `fprintf`

Comment: @LPs It isn't the same program, they are different. I don't think there is any point in posting the whole code (it's kinda long) and also the function load is used at the start (list is empty) and function save at the end (after new elements have been added to the list).

Comment: `List->head->a->name[index]` addresses out of bounds. array index start from `0` to `index-1` (`29`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define S_(v) #v
#define S(v) S_(v) //stringify

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 30 //index is bad name

typedef struct dataR* data;
struct dataR{
    int age;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
};

typedef struct nodeR* node;
struct nodeR{
    data a;
    node next;
};

typedef struct listR* list;
struct listR{
    node head, tail, curr;//curr unused?
    int size;
};

list list_create(void){
    list List = malloc(sizeof(*List));
    assert(List);
    List->curr = List->tail = List->head = NULL;
    List->size=0;
    return List;
}

void addList(list List, data new_data){
    node new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->a = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if(List->head == NULL)
        List->head = List->tail = new_node;
    else
        List->tail = List->tail->next = new_node;
    ++List->size;
}

list load(const char *filename, list List){
    FILE *fd = fopen(filename,"r");//"filename"--> filename, LOL
    if(!fd){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s can't open in load.\n", filename);
        perror("fopen");
        return NULL;
    }
    int age;
    while(EOF != fscanf(fd, "%d", &age)){// or 1 == fscanf(fd, "%d", &age)){
        data new_data = malloc(sizeof(*new_data));
        new_data->age = age;
        fscanf(fd, "%" S(MAX_NAME_LENGTH) "s", new_data->name);
        addList(List, new_data);
    }
    fclose(fd);
    //fd=NULL;//meaningless
    return List;//need return value;
}

void save(const char *filename, list List){
    FILE *fd=fopen(filename, "w");
    if(!fd){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s can't open in save.\n", filename);
        perror("fopen");
        return ;
    }
    //fwrite(List->head->a, sizeof(struct dataR),1,fd);//fwrite doesn't match load
    node tmp = List->head;
    while(tmp){
        fprintf(fd, "%d %s\n", tmp->a->age, tmp->a->name);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    fclose(fd);
}

int main(void){
    list List = list_create();

    load("list.txt", List);
    printf("List hold %d data.\n", List->size);
    data addData = malloc(sizeof(*addData));
    addData->age = 73;
    strcpy(addData->name, "Ken");
    addList(List, addData);
    save("list.txt", List);
    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Your post is really helpfull. Have a nice day and be well.